# Expanding the number of decimal points in the output of the xtscc command

Tags: output, stata, p-value

I am using the *community-contributed* Stata command `xtscc` and I need to report p-values with `4` decimal points.

Including the `pformat()` option in the `regress` command works:

```
regress y x, pformat(%5.4f)
```

However, when I include this in the `xtscc` command, it results in an error:

```
xtscc y x, pformat(%5.4f)
option pformat() not allowed
r(198);
```

How can I produce the same output when using the `xtscc` command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such option for the `xtscc` command but the following works all the same:

```
webuse grunfeld, clear
estimates clear

xtscc invest mvalue kstock, fe lag(4)

Regression with Driscoll-Kraay standard errors   Number of obs     =       200
Method: Fixed-effects regression                 Number of groups  =        10
Group variable (i): company                      F(  2,     9)     =     84.69
maximum lag: 4                                   Prob > F          =    0.0000
                                                 within R-squared  =    0.7668

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             |             Drisc/Kraay
      invest |      Coef.   Std. Err.      t    P>|t|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
      mvalue |   .1101238   .0195826     5.62   0.000     .0658249    .1544227
      kstock |   .3100653   .0330158     9.39   0.000     .2353784    .3847523
       _cons |  -58.74393   23.71437    -2.48   0.035    -112.3896   -5.098296
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

estimates store m1

estimates table m1, b se p(%5.4f)

---------------------------
    Variable |     m1      
-------------+-------------
      mvalue |   .1101238  
             |  .01958261  
             |     0.0003  
      kstock |  .31006534  
             |  .03301581  
             |     0.0000  
       _cons | -58.743932  
             |  23.714371  
             |     0.0352  
---------------------------
             legend: b/se/p
```